# How to add an error message to the form in Zend Framework 2?

Tags: php, validation, zend-framework2, zend-form, validationerror

I have a complex `Zend\Form` with multiple nested `Fieldset`s. Now I need to implement a cross-`Fieldset`-validation. That means, the validation rule refers to multiple `Element`s from different `Fieldset`s. The only way I found to do that, is to implement this validation in `MyForm#isValid()`, since it's the single place, where I can access every `Fieldset` from.

```
MyForm extends Form
{
    public function isValid()
    {
        $isFormValid = parent::isValid();
        $isCrossFieldsetVaidationOk = // my additional validation logic
        return $isFormValid && $isCrossFieldsetVaidationOk;
    }
}
```

Not tested yet, but it will work. The problem is in adding of error messages.

I've tried

```
$this->setMessages(array_merge(
    $this->getMessages(), ['my new message'])
);
```

But it doesn't work.

How can I add `Form` error messages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Errors messages are link to the form's elements, not directly to the form. So as *newage* said, you have to set the message for a specific element (so his answer is valid and I upvoted it :-) ).

But as you extends Form, you can set you own error messages method directly in the form :

```
MyForm extends Form
{

    protected $errorMessages = [];

    public function isValid()
    {
        $isFormValid = parent::isValid();
        $isCrossFieldsetValidationOk = // your additional validation logic

        if (!$isCrossFieldsetValidationOk) {
            $this->addErrorMessage('Oh oh... Cross-fieldset validation error...');
        }
        return $isFormValid && $isCrossFieldsetValidationOk;
    }

    public function addErrorMessage($text)
    {
        $this->errorMessages[] = $text ;
        return $this; // For a fluent setter
    }

    public function getErrorMessages()
    {
        return $this->errorMessages ;
    }

    public function getMessages($elementName = null)
    {
        if ($elementName) {
            $messages = parent::getMessages($elementName);
        } else {
            $messages = array_merge($this->getErrorMessages(), parent::getMessages($elementName));
        }
        return $messages;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Actually, this way I can make my form save the "form error messages" and retrieve them. The next step is to integrate them with the `Element`s' messages, so that the are displayed together. To do that the `Element#getMessages(...)` has to be overridden. I'll extend your answer with it. Or maybe there is a better solution?

Answer (score 6):

Need join a message for an element of form.

```
$form->get('password')->setMessages(['Wrong password']);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But it's not the element, that is invalid, it's a condition across multiple `Element`s (in different `Fieldset`s). E.g.: There are multiple `foo` `Element`s (we cannot know how many, they are added dynamically) of different `Fieldset`s. At least one `foo` has to be set/filled. Another example: There are multiple `bar` Elements. The sum of their values has to be more than `x`. In both cases the `Element`'s value itself cannot be valid or invalid. It's why I'm looking for a way to define a validation "across the `Fieldset`s" and add the messages directly to the `Form`.

Comment: @automatix Maybe this link will help you. http://circlical.com/blog/2015/7/6/zend-framework-2-forms-factories-inputfilters-and-hydration

Comment: It's a nice tutorial, but it doesn't give an answer to my question.